# How to refer the published aar library files in the azure artifact to android app

Tags: android, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

Requirement:

I have two library projects example, projectCoreModules, and projectCoreValidation.

Project A referring these two aar library projects and it's working fine.

current requirement, new project B also wants to refer this two aar library.

So, I created a separate repo for coreModules and CoreValidation projects in Azure DevOps.

Whenever PR is raised, the pipeline build will be triggered and it will publish the aar files.

[image]

I know, we can refer to the azure artifact feeds, in our android apps using the below code in Gradle.

```
 api (group: 'Tst', name: 'TestingPackage', version: '3.1.0', ext: 'jar')
```

Same like this way, Is it possible to refer to the published aar files to projectA and projectB. So that I can reduce the code.

Even though I have tried with the universal package, through the build pipeline I can able to publish as a universal package. But, I was unable to refer those published to ProjectA and ProjectB. so that Gradle build of these two projects gets to succeed.

Comment: Have you checked these similar issues? [Can I publish AAR file is included another AAR file in /libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032608/can-i-publish-aar-file-is-included-another-aar-file-in-libs-folder), [Android Library AAR depending on another library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042803/android-library-aar-depending-on-another-library) and [Is it possible to share library projects between projects when using Android Studio and gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069080/is-it-possible-to-share-library-projects-between-projects-when-using-android-stu)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT, actually my common library files in the azure feed, from which i need to refer it in the both apps projectA and projectB

Answer (score 0):

We are using similar in our project. However instead of using ext: "jar", we don't use any ext and it is working. Try this:

```
api (group: 'Tst', name: 'TestingPackage', version: '3.1.0')
```

I suppose you have already setup your repository source at the project level build.gradle file. We have setup like so

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url project.ARTIFACT_URL
        name project.FEED_NAME
        credentials {
            username project.PROJECT_NAME_ON_AZURE
            password System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN") : project.MAVEN_ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
    }
}
```

}